# Android app for logging screentime sessions

Tags: android, logs

I am searching for an Android app that logs start and end point of each usage, not just the length. I do not need details about the used application, just time and date of when the phone screen was switched on will be enough.

The log should contain information such as:

```
2014-07-13 10:30 switched on
2014-07-13 10:35 switched off
2014-07-13 12:00 switched on
2014-07-13 12:20 switched off
```

Other requirements:

- Ability to export the data
- Unobtrusive, should not interfere with my normal usage.
- Should require minimal permissions, preferably no root and no internet access
- Free of advertisements is strongly preferred.
- A reasonable price is fine

Answer (score 1):

[ActivityWatch](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.activitywatch.android) is still a WIP for Android (works fine on desktop) but looks very promising. Above all, it's FOSS software.

Comment: If you're able to add a screenshot, it will add to your answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Smarter Time](https://www.smartertime.com/) can log the start and end point of each usage, and satisfy all other requirements. But it can be [overkill for the job](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/47497/6389).