# Android app to export time using apps/browsing website to Google Calendar?

Tags: android, time-management, tracking

I'm looking for an Android app that have one of these two (or ideally both) features:

- Track app usage, and export the time to Google Calendar
- Track website visited, and export the time to Google Calendar

App Usage and RescueTime do the job of tracking, but none of them can export the data to Google Calendar. I need to sync it to Google Calendar to import it with ManicTime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found [Smarter Time](https://www.smartertime.com/) is what I need. **It can guess what you're doing based on the time and your location.**

Features:

- Room-level Location
- Learning Capabilities
- Apps and calls tracking
- Desktop Client
- Calendar Integration (can import to Google Calendar)

## My usage

First, I'm not in any affiliation with this app. I have spent a lot of time to search for an app tracking, and this app comes as a miracle to me. I feel that a true time tracking app should be intelligent enough to know what you're doing **without asking**, and this *combination of ideas* can do that.

I even took a screenshot back in the days I had sleep dysfunction. You can see how the ups and downs in my sleep time affect other activities. It's not that having accurate and detailed data isn't important, but the crucial thing in tracking your life is to have the fundamental understanding of what you actual do. I've spent a lot of time to finely choose the correct names for the names of my activities.

[image: screenshot]
<sup>*Led & fleeting*: a group of activities that basically hooks me into them, but not really increases my productivity, like Facebook or YouTube recommendations. They can lead me because they are so good at knowing my interest, but what I get is very fleeting.</sup>

The app use your home WiFi signal to guess your activities. One down side is that they don't allow real-time import/export except there is a strong demand for it.